# most efficient way to look up the same index number in two different lists to compare values

Tags: python, list, loops, simultaneous

I have the following code and it is the **login feature** that I need help with. I have two **lists** - *usernames and passwords*. The login feature asks the user to enter a username and password. If the entered username is in the usernames list AND corresponds to the same index number in the passwords list, THEN, return "Access granted", else "Denied".

I'd be interested in two things for teaching purposes:
a) a simple fix to the problem using the two lists as specified.
b) suggestions as to the best way to solve this problem. (e.g. dictionaries, 2darrays, or anything else).

The issue is needing to iterate through both lists simulatenously and look up the same corresponding index number.

**Example:**

*username1 and pass1  = access granted*
**but**
*username1 and pass2 =access denied*

**CODE:**

```
usernames=["user1","user2","user3"]
passwords=["pass1","pass2","pass3"]

def main():
   mainmenu()


def mainmenu():
   print("****MAIN MENU****")
   print("=======Press L to login :")
   print("=======Press R to register :")
   choice1=input()
   if choice1=="L" or choice1=="l":
      login()
   elif choice1=="R" or choice1=="r":
      register()
   else:
      print("please make a valid selection")

def login():
   print("*****LOGIN SCREEN******")
   username=input("Username: ")
   password=input("Password: ")
   if username in usernames and password in passwords:
      print("yes")
   else:
      print("denied")


def register():
   print("*****REGISTRATION****")
   username=input("Enter a username:")
   password=input("Enter a password:")
   usernames.append(username)
   passwords.append(password)
   answer=input("Do you want to make another registration?")
   if answer=="y":
      register()
   else:
      registration_details()

def registration_details():
   print(usernames)
   print(passwords)

main()
```

Note: I am aware that storing the lists in a 2d array would be an obvious solution/suggestion, but this fix is necessary for pedagogical reasons - i.e students have not yet covered arrays at all. Looking at simple solutions first, but also stackoverflow users would benefit from suggestions to alternate/more efficient methods to solve this problem as well.

UPDATE:

As someone has commented below ...I thought I'd clarify. I'm aware that what is needed is to get at the index numbers of the said values in the lists. My question is - what is the best solution, or some of the solutions. Enumerate. zip. simply using a for loop? It is quite difficult to know how to start in python as there is not just one way ...any comments as to which would be the most idiomatic (pythonic) would also be useful.

**BEST ANSWER:**

This is possibly the best answer, presented below by Damian Lattenero 
The indentation, a common error, below is off. Is it possible to also just make a quick comment on why? How to fix it?

```
def login():
   print("*****LOGIN SCREEN******")
   username=input("Username: ")
   password=input("Password: ")
   for ind, user in enumerate(usernames):
     if username == user and passwords[ind] == password:
       print("correct login")
     else:
       print("invalid username or password")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
*****LOGIN SCREEN******
Username: user3
Password: pass3
invalid username or password
invalid username or password
correct login
>>>
```

Comment: you could do a dictionary where the key, value is username, password, other wise inside of `if username in usernames and password in passwords:` you need to get the index of password and username and compare them

Comment: Thank you - yes, dictionaries and, as mentioned above in my edit, 2d ararys, are obvious suggestions, but at the moment students have only covered lists, so need to work with a solution for that first. Alternate solutions also welcome to supplement answer....Thank you for your suggestion, but I need a solution (written) as to the best way to code getting the index of password and username. That's what I'm after...

Comment: Hi miss, I am not sure if I understand you... What kind of indentation problem?

Comment: ah - if you look in my edit (at the end), the code there is your solution, but the indentation issue remains. It produces multiple "invalid entry" before "correct login" statements - I'm assuming because of the indentation. Are you able to shed some light on why it's wrong. If you try it with user3 and pass3, you'll note the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use dictionary in this case, look I'll show you how:

```
users_pass = {"user1" : "pass1", "user2":"pass2", "user3":"pass3"}

def login():
   print("*****LOGIN SCREEN******")
   username=input("Username: ")
   password=input("Password: ")
   if username not in users_pass:
      print("The user doesnt exist")
   elif users_pass[username] == password:
      print("password ok")


def register():
   print("*****REGISTRATION****")
   username=input("Enter a username:")
   password=input("Enter a password:")
   users_pass[username] = password
   answer=input("Do you want to make another registration?")
   if answer=="y":
      register()
   else:
      registration_details()
```

if you only want to use lists:

```
usernames=["user1","user2","user3"]
passwords=["pass1","pass2","pass3"]

def login():
  print("*****LOGIN SCREEN******")
  username=input("Username: ")
  password=input("Password: ")
  for index_of_current_user, current_user in enumerate(usernames): #enumerate allows to you to go throw the list and gives to you the current element, and the index of the current element
    if username == current_user and passwords[index_of_current_user] == password: #since the two list are linked, you can use the index of the user to get the password in the passwords list
      print("correct login")
    else:
      print("invalid username or password")

def register():
  print("*****REGISTRATION****")
  username=input("Enter a username:")
  password=input("Enter a password:")
  users_pass[username] = password
  answer=input("Do you want to make another registration?")
  if answer=="y":
    register()
  else:
    registration_details()
```

Comment: could you populate the users_pass={} with some data so we can see what goes in and what would come out ....

Comment: Thank you, and could you also, in your second answer (lists) explain what "ind" is .... perhaps with a comment on that particular line. Thank you so much! I'm assuming index, but if you could comment it with a clear explanation that would help students perusing this!

Comment: I would like to select your second answer as an answer, but the indentation appears wrong. On selecting user2 and pass2 it prints an output that repeats the invalid username and "correct login" when found - so not in quite the right place: OUTPUT: Username: user2
Password: pass2
invalid username or password
correct login
invalid username or password
invalid username or password
invalid username or password

Comment: @MissComputing I added now the comments, and ups, it seems to be like you say, I will correct the indentation, thanks

Comment: @MissComputing, indentation correct, I hope I could help you :)

Comment: Thanks - what was wrong with your indentation the first time? I can't compare to the original now. Thank you VERY much for your help

Comment: In the interest of understanding indentation as well as part of this task, I've posted your answer, with the wrong indentation in my update. Could you comment on how to fix it?

Comment: @MissComputing when I copied your code, I had an space hidden, I usually fix indentation problems by using keys SHIFT+TAB in the text editor, and go to the beggining, and from there, start indenting with one TAB at the time :), Don't forget accepting the answer if it was useful :)

Comment: Thank you - I've just edited my question with best answer and a last question on identation. (you can answer it in comments).

Comment: @MissComputing too kind from you :), Good luck in the class! (for you nick name I assume you are a teacher, I use to be too)

Comment: Are you able to answer the indentation question (in my edit).

Comment: The indentation error still remains even in your "answer".If you use test data user3 and pass3, it prints invalid two times, before finally printing "correct login". How can this be fixed?

Comment: @MissComputing , indentation, meaning, indexs in the lists?

Comment: I just mean when you run the code, it doesn't print the correct output:

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44854248/specific-indentation-error-in-nested-if-statement-in-for-loop?noredirect=1#comment76689416_44854248

Answer (score 4):

If you want to teach python foundations...

```
zip(usernames, passwords)
```

leads to

```
dict(zip(usernames, passwords))
```

but you could also do...

```
for (idx, username) in enumerate(usernames):
   valid_password = passwords[idx]
```

Comment: can you explain idx please ...not familiar with that

Comment: It's a variable name.

Comment: Enumerate creates a list of 2-tuples, the first value in each is the index into the array, and the second is the value in the array. `for (idx, username) in enumerate(usernames)` then sets `idx` to the index of each element, and `username` to the value of each, simultaneously.

Comment: `enumerate` is a python builtin. it returns an object that can be used to iterate an iterable alongside the index of each iteration.

Comment: Amendment to my above comment: "Enumerate creates a generator..." not "a list".

Comment: Clever idea using zip here, is a plus one in my opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix to your code, but not recommended, is by using `zip()`.

You need to replace this if statement:

```
if username in usernames and password in passwords:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("denied")
```

by:

```
if (username, password) in zip(usernames, passwords):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("denied")
```

However, you can use a `dict` where you store your unique usernames ans password and then check if the username is in this current dict then check if the password is correct or not.

Comment: I'm going to have a look at this in a minute. Why, though, do you say zip is not recommended? That's important for me to know ...! Regarding the dictionary - could you post the solution. (although as mentioned, students have not come to dictionaries yet, so for my purposes this isn't quite fit for purpose -it may help others on stackoverflow though!)

Comment: @MissComputing Because within `zip()` you need to iterate all over the pairs of `usernames and passwords` also be aware that zip() need that the two lists have the same length if not you'll have a bad results. Within a dictionary you have to look if the key exists or not then check if the value is equal to your input or not. it's more efficient within a dict.

Comment: So zip is only a bad idea if the lists in question are HUGE. For relatively small lists which are definitely of the same size, zip would be recommended? Surely there's a reason for zip - I wonder what it's best use is..

Comment: @MissComputing, no `zip()` isn't a bad idea. Actually zip is a generator which returns tuples. And the operator `in` will chech if the tuple `(username, password) ` is in the tuples generated by zip or not. But in your current case i recommend you using a dict and access your data by it's keys and values.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple more methods, neither of which I'd particularly recommend, but most other decent ways have been covered in previous answers.

These methods might be better for teaching some general programming basics, but not necessarily for teaching Python...

```
# Both methods assume usernames are unique

usernames=["user1","user2","user3"]
passwords=["pass1","pass2","pass3"]

username = "user2"
password = "pass2"


# Method 1, with try-catch

try:
  idx = usernames.index(username)
except ValueError:
  idx = None

if idx is not None and password == passwords[idx]:
  print "yes1"
else:
  print "denied1"


# Method 2, no try-catch

idx = None
if username in usernames:
  idx = usernames.index(username)

  if password != passwords[idx]:
    idx = None

if idx is not None:
  print "yes2"
else:
  print "denied2"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a great scenario for the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) functions. If I read your question correctly, you want to

- Iterate across both usernames and passwords simultaneously (zip)
- Keep track of index (enumerate)

Given your two lists (usernames and passwords), you will want to do the following

```python
for i, (username, password) in enumerate(zip(usernames, passwords)):
    print(i, username, password)
```

Here's a description on what's going on.

1) The `zip` function is taking your `usernames` and `passwords` lists and creates a new list (an iterable zip object to be precise) where each username and password is appropriately paired.

```
>>> zip(usernames, passwords)
<zip object at 0x_________> # hmm, cant see the contents

>>> list(zip(usernames, passwords))
[("user1", "pass1"), ("user2", "pass2"), ("user3","pass3")]
```

2) The `enumerate` function is taking a list, and creating a new list (actually an iterable enumerate object) where each item is now paired with an index.

```
>>> enumerate(usernames)
<enumerate object 0x_________> # Lets make this printable

>>> list(enumerate(usernames))
[(0, "user1"), (1, "user2"), (2, "user3")]
```

3) When we combine these, we get the following.

```
>>> list(enumerate(zip(usernames, passwords))
[(0, ("user1", "pass1")), (1, ("user2", "pass2")), (2, ("user3", "pass3"))]
```

This gives us a list where each element is of the form `(index, (username, password))`. Which is super easy to use with a loop!

4) Setup your loop with the above!

```
for i, (username, password) in enumerate(zip(usernames, passwords)):
    # Freely use i, username and password!
```